# DateTimePicker DialogResult.OK

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, datetimepicker

I have following code now:

```
var picker = new DateTimePicker();
var form = new Form();
form.Controls.Add(picker);
var result = form.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Can´t acces this
}
if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //Do when Form closed
}
```

When the form appears, there´s only `picker` on it, no buttons. Now I can only acces `result == DialogResult.Cancel` when I close the form. What I need to do to access branch with `result == DialogResult.OK`

Comment: You need a way for the user to close the form by accepting. Use a button or other means. That's up to you.

Comment: And is there any way how to add buttons and assign them what to do (OK/Cancel) without creating class for that Form?

Comment: Sure. Just create a new project and a new form in the designer for testing, do what you want to be done and have a look how the designer did it in the InitializeComponent() method. You can do the same in your anonymous form in your real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 2 buttons `OK` and `Cancel` onto your form and handle the `Click` events properly. The point is you have to use the `DialogResult` property to close your form instead of the `Close()` method, like this:

```
//Click event handler for your OK button
private void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
//Click event handler for your Cancel button
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Or simply you can use the `DialogResult` property of a `Button` (no need to add code to `Click` event handler):

```
buttonOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
```

**NOTE**: All the above things work  only if you show your form using `ShowDialog()`. ***Otherwise, you have to close your form manually***

Comment: Or, since every form has an "X" button at the top-right, you can eliminate the `Cancel` button and simply handle the `FormClosing` event, where you could evaluate the `FormClosingEventArgs` and glean a lot about what's happening.  Also, you can `Cancel` the close to prevent it, if need be.

Comment: @DonBoitnott the code is just for demonstration, we can in fact **disable** the default Close button and use our own Close button. `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel` also triggers the `FormClosing` event.

Comment: "DialogResult = DialogResult.OK or DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel also triggers the FormClosing event."  <-- incorrect.  These _trigger nothing_.  They are values of an `enum` property.

Comment: @DonBoitnott **Are you thinking me as a NEWBIE in winforms???** I forgot to say that the form should be shown using `ShownDialog()`, when you do this assignment `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`, the `Form` will be closed and of course `FormClosing` is fired.